# how to download Image and audio using Download Manager even if app is close in background

Tags: android

i m trying to download image and audio using jsonObject 
    but the problem is when i close my app in background it not work well

```
code
    public class downloadData extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, ArrayList<modelCBlips>> {
Context context;
String cId;
Utils utils;
private DownloadManager mgr = null;

public downloadData(Context context, String cId) {
    this.context = context;
    this.cId = cId;
    utils = new Utils(context);
    mgr = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    context.registerReceiver(onComplete,
            new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

}


@Override
protected ArrayList<modelCBlips> doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
    ArrayList<modelCBlips> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONArray blipArray = params[0].getJSONArray("Blips");
        for (int i = 0; i < blipArray.length(); i++) {
            modelCBlips mcblips = new modelCBlips();

            JSONObject jObjBlip = blipArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String imagePath = jObjBlip.getString("imagePath");
            String audioPath = jObjBlip.getString("audioPath");



            mcblips.setImagePath(SaveFile(imagePath));
            mcblips.setAudioPath(SaveFile(audioPath));
            list.add(mcblips);
            if (isCancelled())
                System.out.println("istrue");
            else
                System.out.println("not");

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    utils.editor.putString("status" + cId, "Downloading...").commit();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<modelCBlips> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        modelCBlips mcb = list.get(i);
        utils.con.insertCBlips(mcb.getImagePath(), mcb.getAudioPath());
    }
    utils.editor.putString("status" + cId, "Downloaded").commit();
    utils.editor.putBoolean("download" + cId, true).commit();

}

BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
    }
};

public String SaveFile(String path) {
    String startdownloadurl = null;
    try {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
        File directory = cw.getDir("channel" + cId, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdir();
        }
        DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

      /*  Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(path);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                downloadUri);
        String imgnm = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        startdownloadurl = directory + "/";
        System.out.println(" directory " + startdownloadurl);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                        | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle("Demo")
                .setDescription("Something useful. No, really.")
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(startdownloadurl, imgnm);

        mgr.enqueue(request);
        startdownloadurl = directory + "/" + imgnm;
  */
        URL url = new URL(path);

        String imgnm = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 2048);

        startdownloadurl = directory + "/" + imgnm;
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(startdownloadurl);
        byte data[] = new byte[2048];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(data, 0, data.length)) >= 0) {
            output.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception " + e);
    }

    return startdownloadurl;
}

}
```

using this code i m try to download Image and audio file when all image and audio file downloaded successfully and then i ll try to insert in my database

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it in a service as service runs even if app is closed